# C++ Visual Studio warn about indirect includes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header

The following code compiles fine with Visual Studio 2013 (probably because `<iostream>` includes `<limits>`), but the "missing" `#include <limits>` prevents me as C++ newbie sometimes to understand whats going on. For example I realized that `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` is in `<limits>` only after removing `#include <iostream>`.

So how can I force the compiler to require each include explicit?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
}
```

Comment: If you use a function from the standard library, it's always best to explicitly `#include` the header file in which the standard says the function is declared/defined. I don't think there is a way to force the compiler to warn you about indirectly `#include`ed files.

Comment: @RSahu I think this should be possible, gcc does it in this case out of the box.

Comment: That's interesting. If there is a way to do that in Visual Studio 2013, I hope you'll get an answer from someone more knowledgeable.

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't a compiler "Warning" per say, you can have the MSVC compiler output a list of all included files at compile time with the `/showIncludes` flag [MSDN compiler reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdkef6tk.aspx)